# Using Sub Abstract Class in Java

Tags: java, class, abstract, extend

I Have this class:

```
public abstract class Test {
    public abstract class SubClass extends Test
    {

    }
}
```

I need to access it like this

```
public class JavaApplication1 extends Test.SubClass {

     public JavaApplication1()
     {
         super();
     }
}
```

But having problem with super.
I Cant use it static nor extend Test
What should I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem? What does "I can't use it" mean?

Comment: Anyway, I'd be very surprised if you could extend a non-static inner class from outside its enclosing class at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution: make SubClass a static inner class.

Another possible solution:

```
public class JavaApplication1 extends Test.SubClass {

   public JavaApplication1() {
      new Test() {}.super();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new JavaApplication1();
   }
}

abstract class Test {
   public Test() {
      System.out.println("from Test");
   }

   public abstract class SubClass extends Test {
      public SubClass() {
         System.out.println("from SubClass");
      }
   }
}
```

Which returns:

```
from Test
from Test
from SubClass
```

Comment: I cant do it static because my make class is using it also

Comment: @user2057399: and it looks ugly as all get-out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you extending an inner class from the outside of the class containing it? Inner class should be used only when you need a specific need inside a Class. If there are more classes that could benefit from the services offered by a Class then it shouldn't be inner but a top level class.

Comment: I'm updating a software that I don't have access to all libraries and sourcecode

Answer (score 2):

The problem is accessing an inner class needs an instance of the outer class. So, you can't directly invoke `super()` from your `JavaApplication1` constructor. The closest you can get is by creating a 1-arg constructor, passing the instance of the outer class, and then invoke `super` on that instance: -

```
public JavaApplication1(Test test)
{
    test.super();
}
```

And then invoke the constructor as: -

```
new JavaApplication1(new Test() {});
```

This will work fine. But, with 0-arg constructor, you would have to create an instance of `Test` class first (in this case, an anonymous inner class, since Test is abstract), and then invoke `super()`.

```
public JavaApplication1() {
    new Test() {}.super();
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels.. :)